# How to determine whether a pending tx is a result of a swap in Uniswap?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, txpool, liquidity-provider

Let's say I'm quering mempool, that is, pending transactions. How can I then filter out those that are the result of swaps made via Uniswap of certain liquidity pools? Let's say there're **10** liquidity pools I want to watch.

Will I have to check the field `to` in each transaction? And then compare it with the list of the smart contract addresses of those **10** liquidity pools?

If so, will there be any caveats?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways a swap can be made.

An EOA sends a transaction to a Uniswap router, in which case you query all txs that has the router address in the `tx.to` field. You just watch the router addresses for txs, decode the input parameters to know what is swapped and where.

An EOA transmits a transaction to a contract which is **not** Uniswap router, which runs a function that will internally interact with a Uniswap router/pair to perform a transaction. In this case, you won't be able to detect this in the mempool, unless you're already familiar with this contract and you know that it will perform a swap.

Comment: what's EOA?....

Comment: My question is about Uniswap itself. Therefore the 2nd way won't apply, will it?

Comment: Many trade on uniswap through a 3rd party contract, such as 1inch or a private contract by arbitrage bots. I believe most of transactions are done that way, depends on what you need, you may have to take this into account.